# Using RegExp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was following a JavaScript course. I needed to make a quiz. But I didn't understand something that was in de code.
Why should the second time needs \n\ `Red/Green\n\`
`Teal\n\`
`Yellow\n\`

And not only \n?

```
var questions =[
  {
    prompt: "What color are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n\
    (b) Purple\n(c) Orange",
    answer: "a"
  },
  {
    prompt: "What color are Bananas?\n(a) Teal\n\
    (b) Magenta\n(c) Yellow",
    answer: "c"
  },
  {
    prompt: "What color are strawberries?\n(a) Yellow\n\
    (b) Red\n(c) Blue",
    answer: "b"
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no regex in your question.

Comment: Regular expressions are delimited with `/`, not ```\```. What you're seeing there are multiline strings. The ```\``` at the end escapes the newline (because newlines aren't valid in string literals) allowing the string literal to continue on the next line. (In modern code, they probably would have used a template literal instead, since those can contain unescaped newlines and untagged template literals create strings.)

Comment: No, it isn't. `\n` is a newline escape sequence. So the ```\n\``` you see at the end is a newline (`\n`) followed by a ```\``` escaping the actual literal newline that follows it in the source code (resulting in two newlines in the string).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! It helped me alot!